# How to Drag object by z-axis in python Ursina Engine module?

Tags: python, ursina

I can't drag my 3d `WOOD` object by *z-axis*. I tried:

```
class Wood(Draggable):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            parent='scene'
            model='wood'
            --all another parametres--
        )

# it doesn't work. Wood moving only by x-axis and y-axis.
```

Comment: Please include the minimal reproducable example

Answer (score 0):

Do `.plane_direction=(0,1,0)` and `.lock=(1,1,0)`
Changing plane_direction will point the plane you drag along towards that direction.

You should also set the parent to `scene`, not `'scene'`.